# VSCode Python Shift + Enter Only Sends to Interactive Window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to research this for a while, but can't find the answer.  I'm using the keybinding shift+enter to send the line of code to the Terminal, but it only sends to the Python Interactive.  It looks like VSCode should be able to figure out out where it should send the code automatically, but the only way I can figure it out is to uncheck...

```
Python > Data Science: Send Selection to Interactive Window
```

After doing this shift+enter would execute to the terminal.

I was curious if anyone has ran into this issue and fixed it without unchecking properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a developer on this extension. By default the setting should be sending shift-enter to the terminal. So Send Selection to Interactive Window is false by default. We do have a popup that if you are executing a file with code cells in it (#%% markers) we prompt and ask if you want to send selection to the Interactive Window. If your setting was turned on it might have been that you said yes to this popup or changed the setting a previous time. Do you recall having changed the setting before?

Comment: It's possible when I was first learning about the extension.  I'll deselect it for now until I want to use a markdown.  I appreciate the response!  This answers what I was looking for.